# Setting up CUDA on Mac?

Tags: macos, shell, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu

I'm following the instructions on the NVIDIA website to setup CUDA on my computer. I have completed everything up to "3.2 Install" (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-mac-os-x/index.html#installation). I am not sure how to use the command `cuda-install-samples-8.0.sh`, it says the command is not found. When I try to run make to compile some samples I get the following message:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
expr: syntax error
/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64  -Xcompiler -arch -Xcompiler x86_64  -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_37,code=sm_37 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 -gencode arch=compute_52,code=sm_52 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=sm_60 -gencode arch=compute_60,code=compute_60 -o vectorAdd.o -c vectorAdd.cu
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
nvcc fatal   : GNU C/C++ compiler is no longer supported as a host compiler on Mac OS X.
make: *** [vectorAdd.o] Error 1
```

I'm hoping this just has to do with me not setting the environment variables. I have a MacBook Pro with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M GPU so I'm pretty sure my computer is compatible with CUDA.

I have installed Xcode, and updated it and made sure the command line tools were installed.

```
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: Have you installed Xcode ?

Comment: Edited my post, short answer: yes. Thank you. @PaulR

Comment: Sorry - don't know what else to suggest then - maybe try the nVidia developer forums ?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO which should be used while looking help on a programming problem on a program of you own.

Comment: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." and I need to install CUDA so that I can write my programs, so it's not off-topic. Try helping instead :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer could be found in the following link https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/569#issuecomment-255589932 (bergerjac's answer). Also another error might pop up that could be something along the lines of

```
Unable to open output file 'vectorAdd.o': 'Error opening output file 'vectorAdd.o': Permission denied
```

and so for that I ran the following command

`sudo chown -R your-user-name /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-7.0/samples`

and I believe it works fine.